# Facebook's getUser() doesn't work after uploading app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

My name is Or and I'm building a canvas page for Facebook. 
I used localhost so far to build my app, and after I have finished building it - I uploaded it to iPage and put it on Facebook.
Suddenly now, only when I enter https://apps.facebook.com/APPNAME/ the app can use getUser(), where in all other pages it returns 0.

The weird thing is that on localhost everything worked, and I was able to use getUser() all the time!

I even checked it again right now and it works from localhost.

How do I solve this?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Any absolute links?

- Try using `$_SERVER`

Any `http://example` links?

- try `//example`